# How to use nsga2r multi-objective optimization with one variable?

Tags: r, optimization

I'd like to use multi-objective optimization to find a value of one parameter that minimizes three separate objective functions. I am currently doing so using the `nsga2R` package in `R`. When I try to do so by setting the `varNo` argument to 1 I get the following error:

```
Error in vector("list", popSize) : invalid 'length' argument
```

I think the problem arises in line 10-11 of the `nsga2R` function source code, where the line to create the object `parent` results in a vector of length popSize, rather than a matrix of nrow popSize. My actual use case is more complex, but here is an example that reproduces this problem:

```
#example with just one variable
library(nsga2R)

fitness_1 <- function(x){
  
  f1 <- 10 + x + 4*x^2
  f2 <- -8 + 0.4*x - 0.6*x^2
  f3 <- 12 -3.6*x + x^2 - 0.9 * x^3
  
  return(c(f1,f2,f3))
}

#example of function working
fitness_1(5)

#plot what what this looks like
library(ggplot2)
x <- seq(0.01,1, 0.01)
y <- as.data.frame(t(sapply(x, FUN = fitness_1)))
y$x <- x
ggplot(y, aes(x = x)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = V1)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = V2), color = "blue") +
  geom_line(aes(y = V3), color = "red")


oneV_optim <- nsga2R(fn = fitness_1, varNo = 1, objDim = 3, generations = 10, 
                     popSize = 100, 
                     lowerBounds = 0.1 ,
                     upperBounds = 2)
```

Is there a way to accomplish this without my changing the source code for this function? Or should I not be using NGS2 when I am only optimizing one variable?

Comment: I haven't played with the `nsga2R` function, but your `function_1` is returning a simple vector of values solved using the input parameter `x`.  The form of the functions input parameter to `nsga2R` is not clear to me.

Comment: I've got a working example for an optimization with multiple variables based on this [tutorial](https://rpubs.com/Argaadya/moea) that works and provides only a vector of values to be minimized to the `nsga2R` function, so I *think* think is what I am meant to provide. Do you have another function or package you would recommend?

Answer (score 0):

To clarify the nomenclature, you apparently have 1 variable, `x` and 3 equations.  Do you want to minimize the sum of the 3 equations?  If so, the `optimize` function from the `stats` package may work.  It optimizes on a single variable:

```
fitness_1 <- function(x){
      
      f1 <- 10 + x + 4*x^2
      f2 <- -8 + 0.4*x - 0.6*x^2
      f3 <- 12 -3.6*x + x^2 - 0.9 * x^3
      sumit <- f1 + f2 + f3
      return(sumit)
}

optimize(fitness_1, interval = c(0, 100))

$minimum
[1] 99.99996

$objective
[1] -856204.8
```

However you can see that the `sumit` function is minimized to the upper bound of the interval.  So the solution is somewhat trivial

Comment: Thanks @SteveM. I think more specifically what I am looking for is some of the advantages that come with using multiple objective optimization rather than simply minimizing the sum. Then I can get things like Pareto fronts and use the theory regarding which values are dominant from the MOO literature. But I'm definitely not an expert on MOO

Comment: @m.evans.  OK, but what are your multiple objectives?  Note that a Pareto frontier is usually generated by multiple optimizations using an increasing vector of values on the right hand side (RHS) of a cost constraint.  Multiple objectives are usually defined by using a weighting scheme on the variables of the objective function.  The Pareto process is the same.  Note that objectives can also be added as constraints.

Comment: My actual objective functions are much more complex and involve comparing estimates to true data and minimizing multiple types of biases among them, each returning one value. I had just made up those functions above as an example.  In the end. I was able to get this to work using the `mco` package.